# How to compare every pair of elements inside a NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` filled with only `NSStrings`

I understand that to iterate over a `NSArray` of n elements, all I have to do is use `for (NSString *element in arrayOfElements)`. However, I was wondering if there is specific function that will perform a comparison between every string element in the array with each other. For example, if I have the array:

[@"apple", @"banana", @"peach", @"kiwi"],

how would I do the comparison so apple is compared to banana, peach and then kiwi; and then banana is against peach and wiki, and finally peach is against kiwi?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific to what you mean by "compare".  Are you trying to remove duplicates?  Are you trying to get a count of how many times each item exists in the array?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @wootle. The "compare" function is a custom method that returns either TRUE or FALSE, and its purpose is to decide which elements of the array should be added to another array. The array will not have any duplicates, and every NSString will be unique.

Comment: I think you need to do a loop within a loop as Lyndset points out and you allude to.  I may clarify as an answer to I can put some sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using nested `for` loops, ex:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.count ; i ++) {
    for (int j = i + 1 ; j < array.count ; j ++) {
        // compare array[i] to array [j]
    }
}
```

Edit: And although wottle's suggestion would work, I'd recommend mine in this case, since it won't waste iterations going over the same comparisons multiple times. What I've done in this algorithm by setting `j = i + 1` is compare each element in the array only to the ones after it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) And although, @wottle's answer should work, I personally prefer my answer in this case since it won't iterations by going over comparisons multiple times.

Comment: Yes, your solution will work better.  In terms of being the most optimal performance, I would throw the array.count in a variable so you're not having to hit it so many times.

Answer (score 2):

Given "the array will not have any duplicates, and every NSString will be unique" this sounds like a great case for using `NSSet` classes instead of `NSArray`. `NSMutableSet` provides:

> minusSet:
>
> Removes each object in another given set from the receiving
>   set, if present.

and

> intersectSet:
>
> Removes from the receiving set each object that isn’t a
>   member of another given set.

I'm not sure which operation you're looking for but it sounds like one of those should cover your exact use case.

Comment: Oh, I see... Just to clarify for future answer seekers, this answer is in response to the OP's comment underneath the original question: *"Thanks for commenting wootle. The "compare" function is a custom method that returns either TRUE or FALSE, and its purpose is to decide which elements of the array should be added to another array. The array will not have any duplicates, and every NSString will be unique."*

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is a bit beyond what custom comparators were meant to do.  Typically when you have a list and you want to run a custom comparator, you're doing it to sort the list.  You seem to want to do some specific action when certain items in the list compare to others, and for that, I think a loop within a loop is your best bet.  It won't be very good performance, so hopefully you are not expecting a large array:

```
-(void) compareArrayToSelf
{
    NSArray *array=@[@"apple", @"bananna", @"peach", @"kiwi"];

    for( NSString *value1 in array)
    {
        for( NSString *value2 in array)
        {
            if( ![value1 isEqualToString:value2] && [self compareArrayValue:value1 toOtherValue:value2])
            {
                //Do something with either value1 or value2
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Great suggestion - yes, the array will be relatively small in the size that was in the example.